# How to merge two columns in SAS keeping format

Tags: sas

I have two columns. The first column contains values (count) and the second column the percentage (from the total population). So I have:

count percentage

12    (48%)

14    (29%)

89    (50%)

I would like one column with both parts:

count

12(48%)

14(29%)

89(50%)

I have tried:

```
data mydata1;
  set mydata;
  countper=catx(' ',count, percent);
run;
```

and

```
data mydata1;
  set mydata;
  counter=count || percent;
run;
```

Both of these sort of combine, the 'catx' being more successful, but I lose the brackets and percentage and the number of decimal places in the percentage originally used.

How can I combine these columns as I wish?

Comment: Figured it out, have to format it again:

    data mydata1;
      set mydata;
      counter=count || put(percent, pctfmt.);
    run;

where pctfmt combined with the '.' tells it to format my percentage in a way pre-described, for example using:

    proc format;
      picture pctfmt     
      (round);
    run;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`countper=catx(' ',vvalue(count), vvalue(percent));` will do it for you without requiring a re-formatting.